# Blog headers from Wordpress in Drupal 7 block

Tags: wordpress, drupal, drupal-blocks

We have a website on Drupal 7 and a separate blog running on Wordpress. Im curious if it's possible to create a block that will show headers from the blog and will link to blog entries. Moreover, it should automatically update itself once new blog entry is added.

Please advise if this functionality is achievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure that your Wordpress blog can provide one or more RSS feeds of its content. In the Drupal site you can activate the Aggregator module (it's in core) and extract content from those feeds.  There is also a bunch of other contrib modules that extend (or replace) that functionaliity.

Comment: Thank you! I have initially researched this topic on the Drupal side, but then found explanation on Wordpress rss feed and then figured out the way to use it with aggregator module.